# how to avoid fetching a part of html page which is being called inside another page?

Tags: javascript, html, load

I am calling a .html page(say A.html, which is dynamically created by another software each time a request is made) inside another webpage (say B.html). I am doing this by using the .load() function. Everything works fine but the problem is I donot want the so many "br" tags (empty tags) present at the end of A.html into B.html. Is there any way to avoid fetching those "br" tags into B.html? Any suggestion would be of great help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: its a big piece of code. But surely I can share the excerpt. For loading the file i am using this function inside B.html in a js:
$( "#container" ).load( "../../A.html" );
The A.html file contains:
<form>
some data
</form>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><span class="sequence" id="ruler" style="visibility:hidden; white-space:nowrap;">ACGTN</span>
</body>
</html>

Comment: are the <br> tags in the a.html-file?

Comment: @hamburger yes the br tags are in the a.html file and i donot want to fetch the ones which are in the end of the file as shown in the above comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't avoid loading part of a file when you are just accessing it.

The best option would be to simply remove the extra `<br>` tags from the document to begin with. There is probably a better way to accomplish whatever they are attempting to accomplish.

With some server-side scripting, it could be possible to strip them automatically when you load it, but would probably be pretty bothersome to do.

Instead, if you can't remove the `<br>` elements for some reason, what might be easier, if you are just dealing with a handful of `<br>` tags would be to simply strip them out.

Since you mention using the `load()` function, I'm guessing you are using jQuery.

If that's the case, something like this would cleanly strip out any extra `<br>` tags from the end of the document.

Here is a JSfiddle which will do it: http://jsfiddle.net/dMJ2F/

```
var html = "<p>A</p><br><p>B</p><br><p>C</p><br><br /><br/>";
var $html = $('<div>').append(html);
var $br;

while (($br = $html.find('br:last-child')).length > 0) {
    $br.remove();
}

$('p').text($html.html());
```

Basically, throw the loaded stuff in to a div (in memory), then loop through and remove each `<br>` at the end until there aren't any. You could use regex to do this as well, but it runs a few risks that this jQuery method doesn't.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I would try the same and would get back again.

Answer (score 0):

You shout delete the br-tags in your A.html.

Substitute them by changing the class .sequence with marging-top:30px 
And have an other value in your B.html-file.

You also can run this:

```
$('br', '.sequence').remove();​
```

in the load-function. It will strip all br-tags.

Comment: Thanx for the valuable suggestion but this A.html page is newly created by another software and I can't tinker the A.html page due to limited permissions on the file.

Comment: Thank you again.. I ll try this also and will get back.

Answer (score 0):

You can't avoid fetching a part of your page, but you CAN fetch only a part of it.

According to the [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/load/), you can call load like this:

```
$("#result").load("urlorpage #form-id");
```

That way, you only load the form html inside the result element.

Comment: yes..Thank you..I had an idea about such thing. But as i needed all of the content except those empty tags, so i was wondering if there could be anyway to do that.